# How to change wordpress login/admin/register/password links?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, url-rewriting

I am creating a new website and I am trying to change the URL of login, admin, register, and password URL's.

I have tried many wordpress plugins, but all of them have problems. Unfortunately I don't have to much funds on me, so I am trying to find a free solution to this.

A few that I have tried with no success: 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/hide-login/
https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-login-url/

Is there an alternative plugin that I may have not came across?

Also if you know of a tutorial where I can change it through code, I don't mind that either. Better to learn it then to rely on something else to do it for you all the time, because one day it might not be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another plugin you may want to try is [Better WP Security](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-wp-security/). It lets you change all of those URLs.

Comment: It kind of works. It doesn't exactly let you make user register and admin log-in separate. As for register URL when I change it, it only redirects back to the default register URL. Oh well, not like I wont get traffic because of this. Was just hoping to make it a bit more custom.

Comment: Feel free to mark it as the best answer if it helps! :)